# Squid as Socks5 Proxy server

Tags: proxy, squid, socks

One of my friends lives in a country which they censor websites and they are fighting with techniques that people use to bypass the censorship.

He told me that the only way that he can bypass the censorship now is using SOCKS proxy (that country blocked VPN and SSH connections to outside the world)

I configured a web HTTP-Proxy server with Squid by the steps in this tutorial : http://www.howtoforge.com/linux_secure_browsing_squid

Now my friend can change his IP address and browse websites with a new IP add , but he told me that he still cannot access the censored sites since the browsing is not encoded.

Can anyone help me how I can configure Squid as a Sock5 proxy server ?

My server is Debian 5

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As much as I may sympathize with your friend's plight, ServerFault has a policy of not aiding anyone in the circumvention of *any* existing, authoritative policy that the technology professionals do not have authority over. This question will likely be closed as off-topic unless you can edit yoru question down to the bare minimum and remove all mention of subversion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Squid is an HTTP proxy, not a SOCKS proxy. It expects to talk HTTP and nothing else.

Have a look at [Dante](http://www.inet.no/dante/). I find this to be an easy and reliable SOCKS proxy server.

Comment: http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Socks